# Laravel img src not working with my file path

Tags: html, laravel, image

I am trying to get an image to show up but it's not working, not sure if its my file path or if i'm supposed to call it a different way.  The file path I have my image on is `public/storage/images/aa.png`

I am using 
`<img src="{{asset("images/aa.png")}}" >`
but it's not showing anything, am I supposed to place it on a different path? or am I calling it wrong?  I already tried different suggestions on stackoverflow but none are working for me.

Comment: because the path isn't `images/aa.png` it is `storage/images/aa.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be

```
<img src="{{asset("storage/images/aa.png")}}" >
```